# Change background color in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML each `td` represents a square. I just need to change those squares to yellow if they are white (by default) and to white if they are yellow, by right-clicking. Here is my code:

```
$('tbody').on('contextmenu', 'td', (e) => {
  const td = $(e.currentTarget);

  if (td.css('background-color') !== 'yellow') {
    td.css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
  } else {
    td.css('backgroundColor', 'white');
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is that yellow works but by right-clicking again it never returns to white again.

Comment: Can we have your HTML ?

Comment: The answer is in the first comment, this question must be closed as a typo

Comment: @treyBake They're the same thing. The issue is due to the format of the response from `css()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan really? I thought all `.css()` did was add to the style array with key => value? (thus backgroundColor not being valid)?

Comment: @treyBake nope, it allows both camel case and hyphen notations: http://jsfiddle.net/reusy8x3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use *yellow*'s RGB equivalent *rgb(255, 255, 0)* as the condition:

```js
$('tbody').on('contextmenu','td',(e)=>{
  const td = $(e.target);
  if(td.css('background-color') !== 'rgb(255, 255, 0)'){
    td.css('backgroundColor','yellow');
  }
  else{
    td.css('backgroundColor','white');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Though it is better to use jQuery's `toggleClass()` with minimum lines of code:

```js
$('tbody').on('contextmenu','td',(e)=>{
  const td = $(e.target);
  td.toggleClass('yellow');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue you're going to have here is that the `css('background-color')` getter is going to return an RGB string value, not the colour name. You could certainly check for that instead, but a much simpler approach is to use a CSS class to set the background colour and simply toggle it on each event occurrence:

```js
$('tbody').on('contextmenu', 'td', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(e.target).toggleClass('yellow');
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think there is a typo here. This won't work as it's not surrounding by a tbody in your example, right?

Comment: @cmprogram the `tbody` will be automatically inserted for you by the renderer, it has to exist within the table.

Comment: Fair enough, it appears as though I was unfamiliar with the .contextmenu call.